# Existence of pointwise convergent subsequence of increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]:f\;\text{is increasing}\}$ and $\{f_n\} \subset F$. Does there exist a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ which converges pointwise to some function $f\in F$?

My thoughts:

$f_n$ is continuous except possibly at a countable number of points in $[0,1]$. Let $A_n$ be the set of all points of discontinuity of $f_n$. Consider the set $M=\bigcup_n A_n \cup (\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])$, which is a countable set. By a diagonal argument, it is possible to find a subsequence $\{g_n\}\subset\{f_{n}\}$ which converges at every point of $M$. Then for any $x\in[0,1]\cap M^c$,$$|g_{n}(x)-g_{n+p}(x)|\leq |g_n(x)-g_n(q)|+|g_n(q)-g_{n+p}(q)|+|g_{n+p}(q)-g_{n+p}(x)|$$
where $q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Since $g_n$ and $g_{n+p}$ are continuous at $x$, for any $\epsilon$, we can choose a $q$ to make $|g_n(x)-g_n(q)|+|g_{n+p}(q)-g_{n+p}(x)|\leq \epsilon$. Thus $\{g_n(x)\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $g(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g_n(x)$ and $g$ is the desired function.

Is there any mistakes in my sketch?

Comment: Your $q$ depends on $n$ and $p$ so the argument fails.

Comment: I could prove that this is true if we replace 'pointwise' convergence with 'almost everywhere' convergence, but no luck at obtaining pointwise convergence. Could by any chance this be false? A counterexample would then be really hard to construct, since you would need convergence to only fail on an uncountable null measure set (since we can always construct a subsequence so that it converges on any countable set).